# Qual a melhor forma de escrever o seguinte código jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho o seguinte trecho de código que, basicamente, por meio de uma requisição `jQuery` (`$.ajax()`), usa seletores para buscar elementos de uma página (com conteúdo) e coloca dentro de elementos da página atual usando seletores desta.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/system/json/study/radar/uf-panorama-brasil.php?estado=' + this.sigla,
    success: function (data) {
        //retorna a tabela de #id natureza
        var natureza = $(data).filter("#natureza");
        $("#uf-natureza").html(natureza);

        //retorna a tabela de #id segmento
        var macrossegmento = $(data).filter("#macro");
        $("#uf-macro").html(macrossegmento);

        //retorna tabela de #id federal
        var federal = $(data).filter("#federal");
        $("#uf-programa-federal").html(federal);

        //retorna tabela de #id estadual
        var estadual = $(data).filter("#estadual");
        $("#uf-programa-estadual").html(estadual);

        //retorna tabela de #id municipal
        var municipal = $(data).filter("#municipal");
        $("#uf-programa-municipal").html(municipal);
    }
});
```

Tudo funciona perfeitamente. Minha dúvida é a seguinte: existe alguma forma mais elegante de escrever esse trecho de código? Porque na parte que retorna o resultado os trechos de código estão se repetindo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há muito o que mexer, está bom - bem legível - mas em opinião pessoal eu não gosto de ficar usando variáveis, gasta memória meio que atoa. Eu faria assim:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/system/json/study/radar/uf-panorama-brasil.php?estado=' + this.sigla,
    success: function(data) {
        //retorna a tabela de #id natureza
        $("#uf-natureza").html( $(data).filter("#natureza") );

        //retorna a tabela de #id segmento
        $("#uf-macro").html( $(data).filter("#macro") );

        //retorna tabela de #id federal
        $("#uf-programa-federal").html( $(data).filter("#federal") );

        //retorna tabela de #id estadual
        $("#uf-programa-estadual").html( $(data).filter("#estadual") );

        //retorna tabela de #id municipal
        $("#uf-programa-municipal").html( $(data).filter("#municipal") );
    }
});
```

Ou para deixar mais limpo poderia fazer uma função (acho que funcionaria):

```
function tabela (dado, elemento, filtro) {
    $(elemento).html( $(dado).filter(filtro) );
}

$.ajax({
    url: '/system/json/study/radar/uf-panorama-brasil.php?estado=' + this.sigla,
    success: function (data) {
        //retorna a tabela de #id natureza
        tabela(data, "#uf-natureza", "#natureza");

        //retorna a tabela de #id segmento
        tabela(data, "#uf-macro", "#macro");

        //retorna tabela de #id federal
        tabela(data, "#uf-programa-federal", "#federal");

        //retorna tabela de #id estadual
        tabela(data, "#uf-programa-estadual", "#estadual");

        //retorna tabela de #id municipal
        tabela(data, "#uf-programa-municipal", "#municipal");
    }
});
```

Comment: Vou adotar sua resposta! Obrigado!